# Sorting JSON when using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

Morning all, 
I've been following along the examples in the excellent [iOS Apps With REST APIs](https://grokswift.com/book/) book and as a result using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. One thing I don't see mentioned in the book is how you would sort the incoming json objects into a specific order, eg. date. The code I've pasted below works fine for pulling in the json objects however as far as I can tell, they're automatically ordered by created_by.  I'd like to sort by a different order, lets say my class was called Vegetable and had a name attribute so that I could sort by something like:

```
.sort { $0.name < $1.name }
```

I'll start with the Vegetable class in Vegetable.swift

```
class Vegetable: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable {
    var id: Int?
    var name : String?
    var date: NSDate?
}
```

Inside my JSONSerializer file I have the following, I'm not sure I'd wish to change the order directly in here as I'd prefer some more flexibility with each call.

```
    public func responseArray<T: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: Response<[T], NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
    let serializer = ResponseSerializer<[T], NSError> { request, response, data, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            return .Failure(error!)
        }
        guard let responseData = data else {
            let failureReason = "Array could not be serialized because input data was nil."
            let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
            return .Failure(error)
        }

        let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
        let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, responseData, error)

        switch result {
        case .Success(let value):
            let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(value)

            var objects: [T] = []
            for (_, item) in json {
                if let object = T(json: item) {
                    objects.append(object)
                }
            }
            return .Success(objects)
        case .Failure(let error):
            return .Failure(error)
        }
    }

    return response(responseSerializer: serializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

Then, in my APIManager I have the following function

```
func getAllVegetables(completionHandler: (Result<[Vegetable], NSError>) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(VegetableRouter.GetVegetables())
        .responseArray { (response:Response<[Vegetable], NSError>) in
            completionHandler(response.result)
    }
}
```

Finally, populate my tableview I have:

```
func loadVegetables() {
    self.isLoading = true
    VegetablesAPIManager.sharedInstance.getAllVegetables() {
        result in
        self.isLoading = false
        if self.refreshControl.refreshing {
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }

        guard result.error == nil else {
            print(result.error)
            // TODO: Display Error
            return
        }
        if let fetchedVegetables = result.value {
            self.vegetables = fetchedVegetables
            for vegetable in fetchedVegetables {
                // Nothing here at the moment
            }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData() 
    }

}
```

I appreciate any help I can get with this, Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a NSDate property in your Vegetable class ?

Comment: Yep, I just added a simple class to my question for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a NSDate property, you can sort with the `compare` method of NSDate.

```
let sorted = result.value.sort { $0.date.compare($1.date) == .OrderedAscending }
```

Comment: Thanks, Which file would i be looking to add that?

Comment: Inside loadVegetables() method, right before you add the result to your tableView datasource and reload your tableView.

Comment: When I try that I get the following error: Value of type 'Result<[Vegetable], NSError>' (aka 'Result<Array<Vegetable>, NSError>') has no member 'sortInPlace'. and if I try to call sortInPlace on the results.value! I get Value is get-only property.

Comment: Ah, I got it, so in loadVegetables() I did self.vegetables.sortInPlace { $0.date!.compare($1.date!) == .OrderedDescending } and it works! Many thanks for your help, I'll mark this as answered.